# PHP- SOAP Client method call optional parameters

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I want to connect with wsdl interface, and then send request to specific method with specific parameters (i don't want to send some optional parameters)

you can find the expected request at image below
[request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgKdv.png)

and you can find my request that i sent below
[my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSTYU.png)

and this is my code in PHP to send that request:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("subscribeToService", ['clientcredential' => ['username' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'xxx'], "subscriberid" => "xxxx", "serviceid"    => "xxx"]);
```

the response i get is -1 and that's wrong, how can i send the same request they expect without optional parameters?

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing. Do you know that the additional parameters are optional?

Comment: Yes,  the person who developed the interface said that.

Comment: `-1` doesn't sound like a valid response from a SOAP API. I would raise it with the people who developed the API, if that's all you're getting.

Comment: The method call i do add the optional parameter like this <parameter_name/> even if i don't send it, if there a way to get ride of it

Comment: It sounds like it isn't optional then. Is it optional in the WSDL?

Comment: yes, it is. i don't want the appear in the request, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "appear in the request"?

Comment: If you check out this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSTYU.png, you can see <price/> <subtype/>, that's what i mean by appear.

Comment: What does the WSDL look like?

Comment: thank you, i sent all the parameters to solve the problem